# Accessing a unix domain socket in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash, sockets, unix, dns

I'm trying to write (raw byte transfer, no fancy stuff) some data into a UNIX domain socket in Mac OS X (10.6) from the terminal (bash).

socat is not available and doesn not compile straight from source in OS X. According to google some versions of netcat support UDSs but neither of these do once compiled from source:

http://netcat.sourceforge.net/

http://nc110.sourceforge.net/

Any ideas?

Comment: Unix-domain sockets are just files. You should be able to do regular file-based activities, such as `cat yourfile > /path/to/the/socket` without anything special running.

Comment: No you aren't and no you can't: macbook:Communications emilio$ echo foo > serial
-bash: serial: Operation not supported on socket

Comment: Thanks everyone, but I ended up coding a small C program to do the job. Way easier than getting and building OpenBSD sources via CVS.

Answer (score 3):

OpenBSD's [nc](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=nc) supports `-U` to connect to UNIX-domain sockets, and should be reasonably portable.  Source is in [cvs](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/) (see [anoncvs access](http://www.openbsd.org/anoncvs.html)), and Debian has some [tarballs](http://packages.debian.org/src%3anetcat-openbsd).

Comment: The version of "nc" that ships with Big Sur has the "-U" option. Don't know since when it has that.

Answer (score 1):

A port of OpenBSD's enhanced version of netcat for Darwin can be found at:

http://slagheap.net/darwin/